# How to apply opacity to a Flash Player in Opera?

Tags: html, css, flash, opera, opacity

I have a `div` containing a Flash Player:

```
<div id="player">
    <div id="player2">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/player_mp3_maxi.swf" height="20" width="25">
            <param name="movie" value="flash/player_mp3_maxi.swf">
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#e2dcde" />
            <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=file.mp3&amp;showslider=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;width=25">
        </object>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to make the `div` with id `player` semitransparent. So I applied the CSS property opacity to it:

```
#player{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

This works in Chrome, FF, IE8. But not in Opera 12.16. I need to make it work in this browser.
In Opera12 opacity isn't applied to the Flash Player. How can I solve it?

Comment: what kind of opacity ? you mean transparent background of Flash movie ?

Comment: I mean semitransparent flash movie

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more parameter to your object, "wmode=opaque". This way:

```
<param value="opaque" name="wmode">
```